# Why calling parent's method works on all its children instances?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a parent class in C++ with a method and declared two instances of its children classes. When I call this method on one child instance it makes changes to both children. Why is that, how to correct this?

Code is a bit too complicated to copy here, but I call this first child's method in other function where I move the instance of the child by pointers (first I receive it from other function by pointers too), so maybe there is something wrong with that.

[EDIT]

```
//Parent class:
class TWPerson : public TWObject
{
public:
    ...
    void MakeDamage(int DamagePoints);  //Function that causes problem
    ...
};

void TWPerson::MakeDamage(int DamagePoints)
{
    LifePoints -= DamagePoints;
}

//Child class:
class TWSoldier : public TWPerson
{
    ...
public:
    void Create(int SoldierID);
    ...
};

void TWSoldier::Create(int SoldierID)
{
    UnitID = SoldierID;
    LifePoints = 120;
    IsAlive = true;
}

//Class that stores and uses arrays of TWSoldier class:
class TWArmy
{
private:
    TWSoldier *InfantryDivision;

public:
    TWSoldier* GetUnitPtrByID(int UnitID);
    TWSoldier* CreateInfantryDivision();
};

TWSoldier* TWArmy::GetUnitPtrByID(int UnitID)
{
    for (int SoldierNumber=0; SoldierNumber < SoldiersInitialNumber; SoldierNumber++)
    {
        if (InfantryDivision[SoldierNumber].GetUnitID() == UnitID)
        {
            return &InfantryDivision[SoldierNumber];
        }
    }
}

TWSoldier* TWArmy::CreateInfantryDivision()
{
    static TWSoldier NewInfantryDivision[SoldiersInitialNumber];
    for (int SoldierNumber = 0; SoldierNumber < SoldiersInitialNumber; SoldierNumber++)
    {
        IncreaseUnitID();
        NewInfantryDivision[SoldierNumber].Create(CurrentUnitID);
    }
    return NewInfantryDivision;
}

//Class that gets TWSoldier* from two instances of TWArmy and conducts the problematic method:
class TWGameMode
{
private:
    TWArmy AIArmy;      // First instance of TWArmy that stores TWSoldier
    TWArmy PlayerArmy;  // Second instance of TWArmy that stores TWSoldier

public:
    ...
    auto ReceivePlayerAttackCoordinates();
    void PerformPlayerAttack();
    void PerformAttack(TWSoldier* AttackingUnit, TWSoldier* AttackedUnit);
    ...
};

auto TWGameMode::ReceivePlayerAttackCoordinates()
{
    struct Coordinates {        // Declare a local structure 
        TWSoldier *OwnUnit, *OponentUnit;
    };
    int PlayerUnitID, AIUnitID;
    ...
    TWSoldier* PlayerUnit = PlayerArmy.GetUnitPtrByID(PlayerUnitID);
    TWSoldier* AIUnit = AIArmy.GetUnitPtrByID(AIUnitID);

    return Coordinates{PlayerUnit, AIUnit};
}

void TWGameMode::PerformAttack(TWSoldier* AttackingUnit, TWSoldier* AttackedUnit)
{
    ... // RandomNumber and others calculated here
    if (RandomNumber < AttackingUnitAimCapability)
    {
        AttackedUnit->MakeDamage(AttackingUnitDamage * AttackedUnitDefence);
    }
    ...
}
```

I exaplained some stuff in comments in the code but also quick summary:

TWPerson is the parent class of TWSoldier with a method MakeDamage. TWArmy has array of TWSoldier class instances. There are two different instances of TWArmy (PlayerArmy and AIArmy) in class TWGamemode. Class TWGamemode receives pointers to two different TWSoldiers from different TWArmies and calls MakeDamage method on one of them (AttackedUnit which is a TWSoldier* of AIArmy instance) but changes of this method are visible on the same soldiers in both PlayerArmy and AI
Army arrays of TWSoldiers.

Let me know if you would need some additional information or I missed something.

Comment: Code please,....

Comment: @Tarik I added the code to the question. Let me know if maybe I should simplify it a bit more.

Comment: I guess the main problem is the ` static TWSoldier NewInfantryDivision[SoldiersInitialNumber];` in `CreateInfantryDivision`. Do you know how `static` works here? You probably meant to use `new` to really create a _new_ array instead of overwriting thw existing one. Or even better: use `std::vector`. Sidenote: `GetUnitPtrByID` can lead to undefined behaviour because it doesn't always return something.